# Getting services.wsdl for Microsoft Exchange online

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to write a small Java client for consuming services provided by Microsoft Exchange server through Exchange Web Services (EWS). For experimenting I set up Exchange Online account from [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/exchange/microsoft-exchange-online-email-for-business-FX103739072.aspx).

Then I configured my Outlook client to use the newly created mail on exchange and outlook's Test Email Auto-Configuration windows I tried to retrieve the link for Services.wsdl for that client:

[image]

Then I tried hitting Availability Services url, entered the username and password and it opened following page:

[image]

I then tried to hit the url specified on that page for service.wsdl, but it gave Page Not Found error. SO

- **Q1** where will I get WSDL file, and
- **Q2** which link should I hit while developing Java client. In my office environment I get WSDL file over configured Exchange server which directly opens WSDL file but am guessing what should be in case of exchange online.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Q1** - The WSDL file can be downloaded from the Exchange server endpoint that you wish to hit. I don't have credentials to try this, but this should work:

`https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Services.wsdl`

It's usually in the EWS directory and named Services.wsdl. I just looked at your other screenshots above and inferred the same format.

**Q2** - For Office 365 (which you are testing with), Microsoft recommends [this approach](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/148/p/57006/206833.aspx#206833) for manually finding the URL to hit for API calls. (Alternative much more detailed desciption here: [How to get services.wsdl for Office 365?](http://blog.skysoft-is.com/?p=78))

However building the stubs yourself and finding URLs to invoke is a lot of work that you *don't* have to do if you use a pre-built Java library such as Microsoft's own [EWS Java API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) or this [3rd party library](http://www.independentsoft.com/jwebservices/index.html). They both do basically the same thing, which is to expose Java classes in a Jar that allow you to make calls to any Exchange server. They will also take care of automatically discovering the URL to use, if you wish (it's a feature called [Autodiscover](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591328%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped a lot. Between did you ever tried consuming EWS with Java? Or giving any try to developing a custom Java client for EWS. EWS Java API from microsoft seems kinda buggy from the comments on the same page you linked in your answer.

Comment: I've used both of those libraries to build real Java applications against EWS.

Comment: Is [EWS Java API](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi) good to depend on? I think its development is seized? And also its buggy (from what I cound read from comments on its page)? Isn't it? Need some review on it. Please tell. My final aim will be to export mails as `.msg` files along with the conversation index - MAPI property `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX`.

Comment: Also can you tell if it is fully developed - if everything is possible or you faced any situation where there was functionality that was not there in EWS java API but was there in Independentsoft API?

Comment: I don't know enough about each library's details to recommend either one, sorry. You'll have to choose one based on your own testing. Or, start another question on Stack Overflow to get feedback from others.

Comment: I coudn't find it directly at `[server]/EWS/Services.wsdl`, but  `[server]/EWS/Exchange.asmx` gave me what I wanted.